# Escaping Double Quotes, Space and Allowing for an Extra Forward Slash

Tags: xslt

I have XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<icestats>
    <stats_connections>0</stats_connections>
    <source mount="/live">
        <bitrate>Some data</bitrate>
        <server_description>This is what I want to return</server_description>
    </source>
</icestats>
```

And I have XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/icestats/source mount="/live"/server_description/node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want the output

```
This is what I want to return
```

If I remove the double quotes, space and forward slash from the source it works, but I haven't been able to successfully escape the non standard characters yet using suggested methods in other posts.

---

For clarity, below is the solution thanks to Lego Stormtroopr

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="/icestats/source[@mount='/live']/server_description/node()" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues you will need to resolve before your processor will produce the output you're looking for.

1) Your XML input must be made well-formed. The closing tag of the `source` element should not include the `mount` attribute that is specified on the opening tag.

```
<source mount="/live">
   ...
</source>
```

2) The XPath on your `xsl:copy-of` element must be made valid. The syntax for an XPath expression is (fortunately) not like the syntax for XML elements and attributes. Specifying which `source` element to match is done by predicating on an attribute value, like you have done, except that you need to use square brackets:

```
/icestats/source[@mount="/live"]/server_description
```

In order to use this XPath expression in an XSLT `select` statement, you will need to make sure that you enclose the entire `select` attribute value with one type of quotes, and use the other type of quotes within the attribute value, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/icestats/source[@mount='/live']/server_description" />
```

With This input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<icestats>
    <stats_connections>0</stats_connections>
    <source mount="/live">
        <bitrate>Some data</bitrate>
        <server_description>This is what I want to return</server_description>
    </source>
</icestats>
```

and this stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="/icestats/source[@mount='/live']/server_description" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following line of text from xsltproc and saxon:

```
This is what I want to return
```

The `xsl:value-of` element will return the string value of an element (here, that one text node). If you actually wanted the `server_description` element, then you can use `xsl:copy-of` to get the whole thing, tags and all. (You would have to update `xsl:output` as well.)

Comment: Thanks for this. 'copy-of' was returning the correct output, although I have a feeling 'value-of' is more suitable. Although I don't fully understand the difference (beyond what you said... to include the tags somehow).

Comment: The `copy-of` XPath in your final answer includes an additional node test, `node()`, that causes the text-node child of `server_description` to be selected. The `value-of` XPath causes only `server_description` to be selected, but `value-of` returns the string value of that element. Given the content of `server_description` in this example, those two will produce the same output.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing a select based on the attribute, so you just need to properly capture the attribute in the XPath. The quotes you use in the document and the XPath don't need to match, so you can switch them to single quotes (`'`):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/icestats/source[@mount='/live']/server_description/node()" />
```

(Edited to correct the the missing `/` from the `mount` attribute.)

Also, your original document isn't valid XML, as XML doesn't allow attributes in the closing tag.

Comment: OK thanks, seems like it's on the right track. I hadn't thought of that. It's parsing, but the result is blank.

Sorry about the closing tag. It's not like that. I have amended the question.

Comment: Got it, you forgot the forward slash. Thanks for the help. I'll post the full solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is escape the quotes in the attribute string with `&quot;`:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/icestats/source mount=&quot;/live&quot;/server_description/node()" />
```

Comment: That's not parsing. I did try that. Could it be the extra forward slash in the node title confusing the 'copy-of select'?

Comment: @square_eyes - Ah. It would have been helpful if you had explained what you had actually tried (instead of the vague "suggested methods in other posts").